# Failed to create user with Ansible postgresql_user module

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I have Ansible playbook that is applied to virtual machine. The plyabook is installing Postgresql DB, set up the connection parameters in `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`. But now I want to create a new user with `REPLICATION` role using `postgresql_user` module. But receive an error when doing this:

```
fatal: [10.0.15.20]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "db": "",
            "encrypted": false,
            "expires": null,
            "fail_on_user": true,
            "login_host": "",
            "login_password": "",
            "login_unix_socket": "",
            "login_user": "postgres",
            "name": "replicador",
            "no_password_changes": false,
            "password": null,
            "port": "5432",
            "priv": null,
            "role_attr_flags": "REPLICATION",
            "state": "present",
            "user": "replicador"
        },
        "module_name": "postgresql_user"
    },
    "msg": "unable to connect to database: could not connect to server: No such file or directory\n\tIs the server running locally and accepting\n\tconnections on Unix domain socket \"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432\"?\n"
}
```

The only thing that I could found is that I need to use

```
become: yes
become_user: postgres
```

However it didn't change anything

Here is my ansible task:

```
- name: create repication user
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user:
    state: present
    name: replicador
    encrypted: no
    role_attr_flags: REPLICATION
```

And postgresql setting in `postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And `pg_hba.conf`

```
host       all         all        all           trust
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your error postgres is trying to connect to server via unix socket instead of tcp one. You should either add the following string to `pg_hba.conf`

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

to trust all unix socket connections or try to specify `login_host: 127.0.0.1` to postgresql_user role. That part is actually strange, because as per documentation login_host defaults to localhost.

And also make sure that your database is really running, just in case you missed that part somewhere in your playbook.

Comment: Even though I had the handler that should restart the postgresql, and it was trigged, looks like it wasn't started when I was trying to create the user. I moved it after the postrgesql service starting task and it works. Thank you!